# PL/SQL: Identifier must be declared

Tags: java, sql, plsql

I'm a beginner to PL/SQL so this issue is stumping me. I have some PL/SQL code:

```
create or replace package p2 as
  procedure show_students(ref_cursor out sys_refcursor);
  ... 
end;
/
show errors

create or replace package body p2 as
procedure show_students(ref_cursor out sys_refcursor) is
begin
    open ref_cursor for SELECT * FROM students;
end;
...
end;
/
show errors
```

and I also have this Java code:

```
public static void showTable( int option, Connection conn ) {
    try {
        CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall( "begin p2.show_students(?); end;" ) ;
        cs.registerOutParameter( 1, OracleTypes.CURSOR ) ;
        cs.execute() ;
        ResultSet rs = (ResultSet)cs.getObject( 1 ) ;
        while ( rs.next()) {
          System.out.println( rs.getString(1) + "\t" +
                              rs.getString(2) + "\t" + rs.getString(3) + 
                              rs.getString(4) + 
                              "\t" + rs.getDouble(5) + "\t" +
                              rs.getString(6)) ;
        }
        cs.close() ;
      }
      catch( SQLException ex ) {
        System.out.println( "SQL Exception " + ex.getMessage()) ;
      }
```

When I run the Java program, I get the following error:

```
SQL Exception ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'P2.SHOW_STUDENTS' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

... I have no idea what is causing the issue. Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You must call the procedure like this :

```
CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{call show_students (?)}");
```

There can be no other procedure with the name then p2. no need to mention

Comment: I get the same issue even with this code :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't have all the answers but that error usually occurs due to a permissions issue. i.e. Your code doesn't have permission to run the SQL procedure.

You should try doing some GRANT statements

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).